# Символьные константы в языке Си

Tags: c, символы, ansi

Вопрос больше философского характера, чем технического. По определению ***константой*** в языке Си назвается такая переменная, которую нельзя изменять по ходу выполнения программы и такая переменная доступна только для чтения. Вопрос с объявлением ***числовых констант*** отпадает сразу - и так ясно, что имеется в виду

```
int const a = 5;
```

Такое объявление и описание не вызывает особых трудностей для понимания. Что же подразуемвается под ***символьной константой***? Языком лысого ёжика, это числовой код, которому соответствует символьное отображение (ASCII-код). Но что здесь является константой; в чем ***выражается неизменность?*** Что каждому символу соответствует данный код? Но как мы его изменим? Ведь язык не допускает такую конструкцию:

```
'a' = 666;
```

Вопрос, на которого я требую ответа: ***"В чем выражается неизменность символьных констант?"***

Comment: Если под числовой константой ты понимаешь _`int const a = 5;`,_ то почему под символьной не `const char b = 'b';`, а просто `'b'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Термин *константа* в языке С имеет строгое определение. По определению, термин *константа* обозначает именно и только буквальные литеральные значения: `25`, `'f'`, `0x13`, `3.1415`. Также термин *константа* в языке С распространяется на члены перечислений, результат `_Alignof` и `sizeof` (с некоторыми исключениями). Это все.

Объекты, объявленные со спецификатором `const`, константами в языке С **не являются**. Ваше

```
int const a = 5;
```

это ни в коем случае не *константа* в языке С (!). Это просто, скажем так, "немодифицируемая переменная".

Важность правильного понимания термина *константа* обуславливается тем, что ряд контекстов в языке С требует использования именно констант и константных выражений. Например, инициализатор для статического объекта должен быть именно константой. Ваше `a` в этой роли использовать не получится

```
int const a = 5;
static int x = a; // Ошибка - инициализатор не константен
```

*Символьными* константами в С называются константы вида `'a'` (также сюда можно причислить мультисимвольные константы вида `'abc'`). Они не являются lvalue. Не существует никаких корректных конструкций языка С, которые могли бы их изменить. В этом и заключается их "неизменность". То есть вторая часть вашего вопроса действительно содержит правильный ответ. Невозможно "изменить" то, что не является lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

> Символьная константа – это некоторый символ алфавита, заключенный в
>   одиночные кавычки.

Значением символьной константы является целое число, равное ASCII коду 
 данного символа. Символьная константа имеет тип int или char и размерно состовляет 16 или 8 бит, соответственно.

Comment: В int'е 16 бит было лет 20 назад... К тому же, было бы неплохо указать, в каком случае int, а в каком char. Тем более, что у вопроса нет метки c++, значит всегда int.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78318/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-newview).